# How do I enable HTTPS on a Cloud Run for Anthos on Google Cloud cluster?

Tags: https, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-run, google-anthos

I recently started fiddling with Cloud Run for Anthos on GoogleCloud and I just can't enable HTTPS access. I've followed every step in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/gke/enabling-cluster-https) but it still doesn't work. I have a custom .dev domain which I configured through [these steps](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/gke/default-domain#testing_with_a_custom_domain) and everything is fine with HTTP but HTTPS still says `connection refused`

`curl http://api.default.customdomain.dev` - works fine

but `curl https://api.default.customdomain.dev` - says:

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to api.default.customdomain.dev port 443: Connection refused

I'm pretty sure there's something not specified in the docs, it happens a lot with GCP docs. Has anyone else struggled with this and might be able to help? Thanks!

EDIT: It was actually my fault - when [creating the cert/private key secret](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/gke/enabling-cluster-https#secret) I provided `default` for the `--namespace` value instead of `gke-system`. So, yeah... it's fixed now.

Comment: Can you provide your config files and your image spec (Dockefile if you built it yourself). The error message sounds like pot 443 isn't open on the image, though that's just a guess currently

Comment: Can you show us what your Gateway spec looks like, as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/gke/enabling-cluster-https#configuring_the_gateway)?

Comment: Hi @IonutAchim, I am glad that you fixed your issue. Can you please post an answer with the solution to the issue for visibility to other community users who may run into the same issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was actually my fault - when [creating the cert/private key secret](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/gke/enabling-cluster-https#secret) I provided `default` for the `--namespace` value instead of `gke-system`. So, yeah... it's fixed now.